# Qual é a diferença entre dois trechos de código com e sem construtor?

Tags: kotlin, construtor

Estou tendo dificuldade em entender o que um construtor faz. Ele inicializa uma variável para ela não ser nula? Se sim, isso não seria resolvido facilmente fazendo o que está escrito no segundo trecho de código?

```
public class Node<E> {
    var previous: Node<E>? = null
    var next: Node<E>? = null
    var value: E? = null

    constructor(e: E) {
        value = e
    }
}
```

```
public class Node<E>(e: E) {
    var prev: Node<E>? = null
    var next: Node<E>? = null
    var value: E? = e
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seria interessante ver isto: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Quando você inicializa um campo na classe está dizendo que quer que o compilador escreva um construtor para você onde ele faça a inicialização toda vez que instanciar essa classe e você não se importa com a ordem que ele vai fazer isto e nem quer que faça nada adicional.

Se essa garantia não é suficiente e quer mais, quer ter o controle de como inicializar os campos, então pode escrever o construtor por conta própria.

Mas tem uma pegadinha no primeiro código. Um dos construtores faz exatamente o que o compilador faria nessa exata situação. Mas também foi criado um construtor vazio (sem parâmetros) que não inicializa o mesmo campo, portanto o valor dele será nulo na inicialização se chamar esse construtor. Pode ter sido intencional ou acidental, mas o primeiro código tem essa capacidade, o segundo não tem, o campo será inicializado em todas as instâncias se o construtor vazio for chamado, já que as inicializações que o compilador coloca não existirão nesse método.